# What is the best way to model one to many relationship in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am thinking of implementing a followers, following relationship using Mongoose.

On a very simple way, I believe the easiest way to make a user follow another user is by using an array and adding that user_id to the array as below

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        api_key: String,
        followers:Array
    }
```

To add a user to the user followers list I did

```
....const user = await User.findOne(...);
    user.followers.push(user_id_of_follower);
```

The above works but I'm a little bit skeptical. What if a user has **1 billion followers**, is the above array pattern the best way to model a follower/following relationship in mongodb?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think for heavy data and big data its better to create another collection with
this type

```
{
  user_id:"123",
  follower_id : "222"
}
```

when a user follows a new user add new records, and you could add a new field in the user for a count of followers and following
when you want to get a list of followers of the specific user in my solution you could be using paging, skip